# pods have no access to the internet

Tags: docker, kubernetes, networking, iptables, flannel

I have a freshly created kubernetes cluster set on 2 nodes, both nodes are open to the internet. I can curl, ping etc. any web. The problem appear when I try to do the same from pod. eg.
curl to yoururl.com from node returns 200 and some response
the same curl from inside of alpine pod returns 301 Moved Permanently
The k8s network is managed by flannel. What bothers me is iptables Chain Forward that was added after k8s installation (screen below). Is this default behavior of flannel? Should I change it to ACCEPT policy? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are experiencing issues with accessing external websites from your pods, it is possible that your nodes are not configured to use the correct DNS server. You can try adding the following configuration to your pod's YAML

```
spec:   
    dnsPolicy: "Default"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Turned out that my ClusterFirst policy caused an issue. Default one resolved problem. Thanks again. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-dns-policy

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting 301 Status code, it means you have an internet connection and a working dns.
try to ping the address from inside the container to see what IP is being resolved, then compare it to ping, done from your node.